# C# Registry fetch: OpenRemoteBaseKey - "IOExepction: The handle is invalid" error

Tags: c#, .net, windows, registry

I use this simple line to access registries on remote computer (for example CurrentUser):

```
RegistryKey r = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, "machineName");
```

Works perfectly fine, but when I try this line:

```
RegistryKey r2 = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentConfig, "machineName");
```

I get the following error:

> IOExecption was unhandled: The handle is invalid.

The only way I can make it work is to use:

```
RegistryKey r3 = RegistryKey.OpenRemoteBaseKey(RegistryHive.CurrentUser, "");
```

But it will only work on my local machine and this isn't what I need.

OS: Tried on Windows 7 and Windows Server 2012 R2

I've been searching all over the web, but I couldn't find anything to solve that problem. very few are even addressing that error. Any assistance is highly appreciated.

Comment: does the user running the code exist on the other machine?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you mean - But the user execute the code and it should bring the registry from another machine, and it works for every registry except for CurrentConfig